# asp.net javascript generic function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clientid

I'm trying to create a javascript function where I can pass in the ID of the field I want to update. Something like:

```
function populateField(aValue, aField) {

    document.getElementById('<%=' + aField + '.ClientID%>').value = aValue;

}
```

But that's not working - I get a "Too many characters in character literal" error. Any ideas on how I can write this dynamically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: document.getElementById('aField<%= ClientID %>').value = aValue;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the server control's client ID, you need to use like this -  `aField.ClientID` so that it'll run in server side.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="aField"></asp:Label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<%= aField.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "test";
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but how would it work if I were passing in the ID of the field to the javascript function?

Comment: If that is the case, the calling function must have `<%= aField.ClientID %>`. If you want to maintain the client side ID same as server side, you can use `ClientIDMode="Static"`. ***However, I do not recommand that method unless you do not have other option.*** http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx